# contact form 7 shortcode not working in wordpress html code

Tags: contact-form-7

this code is not working in wordpress html code. Can you help me someone.

this code is not working in wordpress html code. Can you help me someone.
[contact-form-7 id="15345" title="JOIN OUR MAILING LIST"]

Answer (score 0):

Shortcodes by default only work within the content of a post.

If you want to use a shortcode in a page template, then you need to use the `do_shortcode()` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/),

```php
echo '<div>'.do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="15345" title="JOIN OUR MAILING LIST"]').'</div>';
```